# How to get continuous output (progress bar) in google script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to obtain a continuous output from a google script to let see  the script progress to the user. I don't need a graphic output, a simple counter should be enough.
I'm trying with

```
function provando() {
  var i = 0;
  do {
    i ++;
    var riga = "Valore di i: "+i;
    var finestra = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput(riga)
    .setTitle("Progresso")
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(75);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(finestra);    
    // Utilities.sleep (500)
  } while (i < 20);
}
```

and the problem is that the variable "riga" is outputted only at the end of the loop.
Is there a way to obtain a continuous output?

Comment: The problem with what you're attempting to do is that you are going to make the user wait even longer just to display a dumb counter that doesn't really tell them jack.  And you cant use a count down because you never really know how long something takes because it depends upon a lot of factors.  So I'd recommend not wasting your time with it.  It's a bad idea.  I will often put a yellow background up on dialogs and when the function completes it returns the background to normal just to let the user now that the round trip has completed from the client to the server and back.

Comment: Hi Ruben, I understand what you say, but the fact is that when you work with classroom the user has to wait a very long time (it takes 20 - 30 minutes to create 100 classrooms), so the counter should be useful.

Comment: If I wanted to let the user know it was still running I'd probably use the `toast()` but I wouldn't want to waist to much time on the display content.  Twenty or Thirty Minutes is pretty long time, have you taken a look at [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Hi MetaMan, it takes so long time because Classroom is very slow; it needs from 30 to 45 seconds to create one classroom manually from web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
let n = 0;
//begin creating classrooms and increment n after every creation 
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(`Classrooms: ${n}`);
```

That's not much extra code and it lets everyone know it's still running and you will now when your finished if you know how many classrooms your creating.

```
let n = number of classrooms your going to create and then decrement.
```

Comment: I'm going to try it, Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your solution matches my needs. Thanks a lot.